# Why is Python's console split in debug perspective in Eclipse with PyDev?

Tags: python, eclipse, console, pydev

When I launch my Python program with the debugger in Eclipse with PyDev (Python plug-in for Eclipse), the console is always split into two windows. One where I can actually enter code and the other displays my code entries and their output. See the following snippet.

[image]

There is also a "dedicated" debug console which I can start whenever my program is paused, but this requires a manual click (PyDev > Debug Console). This console doesn't have the slip view. See snippet.

[image]

Why are there two ways to interact with Python while my program is paused? Why is the default console (from the first screenshot) split into two windows? How can I make my default console be more like the second console without the split view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second bottom console keeps a history of user commands that are injected into the current context. It provides a cleaner input mechanism with the ability to navigate through a history of commands. In addition some programs running loops may print to the original console frequently making it difficult to print commands into the top console.

It may have been added for future features as well, like changing the context of the input to a different spot in the code.

That is just my guess. There is a "hide console prompt" terminal button if you do not want to see it. Both consoles can have commands entered in if you are debugging and paused.

Comment: Great! There IS a button called "hide original console" which does exactly what I was looking for.